# How to define that only one field is written to a particular node?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

example:

if a user is an admin and is not a company, I want the roles node to only have admin: true (and I do not want another child with company: false) or if the user is a company, true (not admin: false)

```
{
// BAD
{
    "roles": {
        "$key": {
            "admin": true,   // or admin: false
            "company": false // or company: true
        }
    }
}
// GOOD (but how to make?)
{
    "roles": {
        "$key": {
            "admin": true, // or company: true
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Use a [cloud function listener](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D+onWrite) to trigger `functions.database.ref('/roles/{key}/admin').onWrite`.  If true, then `remove` the adjacent company key.

Comment: Have a look at the "validating data" part of the RTDB security rules: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#validating_data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add a catch-all rule to reject unmatched child nodes:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "roles": {
      "$key": {
        "admin": {
          ".validate": "newData.isBoolean()"
        },
        "$other": {
          ".validate": false
        }
      }
    }
}
```

So with the above rules, each `role` can only have an `admin` property with a boolean value. If a client tries to write any other properties, that write will be rejected.